# exporting specific data from MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `users` which has the following columns: `id`, `username`, and `address`.

How can I export just the `username` column to either CSV or an Excel-readable format?

Comment: export to csv or excel format

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `username` INTO `backup` FROM `users`
```

Moves username into table backup from the users table

EDIT: Didn't know you wanted to export to csv.  You should install phpmyadmin, best system to work with this.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp is the source.